# Creating .bak file from a .mdf without being attached in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database-backups

I have an .mdf file from SQL Server, which I need to create a .bak file from. I can't attach the database in SQL server because it seems to be corrupted and I want to try to restoring it using a .bak file.

Is there a way to create a .bak file without the .mdf file being attached in SQL Server?

Is it possible to do it via cmd line?

Comment: Both .bak and .mdf are proprietary file extensions, meaning you need sql server to produce (and read) them. Why do you think you can create and restore a backup from a corrupt database file?

Comment: I attached the .mdf on one of my clients on friday, and suddenly there was a problem with it. It said it was recovery pending and when i tried to detach and reattach I was presented with an error advising me to restore it from a backup. Probably means an older backup but wanted to give it a try, since my client was filling it up with data over the weekend. If I could at least somehow see the data inside, i could transfer it to a new DB and move on.